# PHP : Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::

Tags: php, arrays

I am fetching `json` data from a table called `properties`. Column name is attr and it has size,bedrooms and prop-type in it.

```
  $q= mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM properties");
    $savemyval = array();
    while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
        $data = json_decode($row['attr']);
          //var_dump($data);
          if($proptpe == $data->proptype){
                $savemyval[] = $row['id'];

            }
  }
```

Querying data like above if i var_dump this is what i get

```
object(stdClass)[3]
  public 'bedrooms' => string '5' (length=1)
  public 'proptype' => string 'residential' (length=11)
object(stdClass)[4]
  public 'bedrooms' => string '4' (length=1)
  public 'proptype' => string 'commercial' (length=10)
object(stdClass)[3]
  public 'size' => string '16000' (length=5)
  public 'prop-type' => string 'commercial' (length=10)
```

in var_dump i get proper data but when i try to get proprtype, if its more than 1 it gives me the error

> PHP : Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::

if I use isset then there is no error but still it prints one result while dumping gives me more than 1 results

Answer (score 0):

Because in your array you doesn't have proptype on second index

try like this

```
if(isset( $data['proptype']) && $proptpe == $data->proptype){
       $savemyval[] = $row['id'];

}
```

Comment: this is what i get  Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array